# function to set permalink to /%postname%/ on theme activation

Tags: permalinks

I'm wondering if there is any function to set permalink to `/%postname%/` on theme activation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could, but I'd actually highly advise against that. In quite a few cases that will cause lots of 404 errors.